# Ubuntu not syncing install

Tags: login

First time installing Ubuntu, I did not leave the US keyboard layout alone, and now the cryptsetup failed, bad password. When trying to reinstall from the USB shows:  end kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (1,0).
How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I recommend you to clean the drive that you installed ubuntu and also clean your usb. And add burn ubuntu back into the usb using win32diskimager or any other disk burner you use. Also, when you boot make sure you choose between legacy(which just says your usb name) and UEFI.
If your dual booting along side windows or mac, you must have the same partition type. UEFI can not be next to Legacy. 
Now just do the install again and if it doesn't work pm me and I'll try to help.